# perf-report reports cache misses in [unknown] shared object with address 0

Tags: linux, perf

```
Samples: 3M of event 'cache-misses', Event count (approx.): 35941375181
  Children      Self  Command    Shared Object            Symbol                                                                                                                                                                            
    14.74%    14.72%  exe        exe                      [.] symbolA                                                                                                              
+   12.07%     0.00%  exe        [unknown]                [.] 0000000000000000                                                                                                                                                        
+   10.33%     0.00%  exe        [unknown]                [.] 0x0000000300000002                                                                                                                                                      
+    9.09%     0.00%  exe        [unknown]                [k] 0x3ff0000000000000                                                                                                                                                      
+    7.67%     7.67%  exe        exe                      [.] symbolB
```

How is it possible, that a shared library is involved, for which the system does not have a file-name?